# Create API with Firestore and Cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Does anyone know the links, tutorials on how to make and API for third party aps using firestore and cloud functions.

I am using google IoT core, firestore, cloud functions. I would like to make an API where 3rd party aps could get access to my firestore DB to control IoT devices. I want to create them a api token or key to get access. I would like also track api calls for every 3rd party app.

I am not sure what is proper way to do it with firestore.

Any links, suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: You could have a look at the doc (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) and in particular https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events, at the following set of videos from the Firebase team (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA&t=328s and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=652XeeKNHSk&t=308s) and finally at the samples: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Could you post your comment as an answer, please?

Comment: @RubénC. Done, thx!

Answer (score 1):

You could:

1. Have a look at the doc (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) and in particular https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events,
2. Watch the following set of videos from the Firebase team (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=652XeeKNHSk)
3. And finally study some of the official samples: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples

Comment: Thanks @Renaud! I Check the links you posted. I still can´t get the idea on how to:

Comment: Thanks @Renaud! I Check the links you posted. I still can´t get the idea on how to:  
Create a REST api where I give a access to the particular user data in firestore. Basically, I thought of making first a user in Firestore and give a access to this user data via REST api (not from the client where, service first must authenticate to get access token). If the firebase auth tokens would not expire, I would just give this token to 3rd party service, and this token could be used to access user data.